# Android Travis CI Error: Invalid --abi armeabi-v7a for the selected target

Tags: android, arm, travis-ci, android-api-levels

My Travis build keeps failing because apparently it does not recognize the `arm` abi. Here's my full `.travis.yml`:

```
language: android
sudo: required

env:
  global:
  - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=28
  - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3
  - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
  - ANDROID_EMU_API_LEVEL=27

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools # appears twice as per Travis docs
    - build-tools-$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    - android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL
    - android-$ANDROID_EMU_API_LEVEL
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-android-${ANDROID_EMU_API_LEVEL}
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'

before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
  - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
  - $HOME/.android/build-cache

before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-$ANDROID_EMU_API_LEVEL --abi $ANDROID_ABI -c 100M
  - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - android list target
  - ./gradlew clean build
  - ./gradlew test
  - ./gradlew connectedCheck
```

I have also tried to change the abi in the emulator to `google_apis/armeabi-v7a` to no avail. Also tried to add `google_apis` in the system image download. I have currently tried `API_LEVEL` 22, 27 and 28.
What is the issue here?

Comment: Did you solve it? Experiencing a very similar issue..

Comment: still not solved @aleksandrbel

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a`instead of `ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get `Valid ABIs: no ABIs.` `Error: Invalid --abi arm64-v8a for the selected target.`

Comment: Do you know what kind of abi is your target ?

Comment: What do you mean by target? I think Travis default one is armeabi-v7a like their docs says.

Comment: "Error: Invalid --abi armeabi-v7a for the selected target" means that the target is not the good one, you can also try `x86` and `x86_64`, `Valid ABIs: no ABIs.` your target may be not recognized
Sorry but I I can't help you any more

Comment: Yeah... Travis doesn't support x86 yet. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant since it was asked 4 months ago, but I also just recently had this same issue. I tried many different things people suggested and none of it worked till I set it up this way:

```
language: android
sudo: required
jdk: oraclejdk8

env:
  global:
  - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=28
  - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3
  - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - extra-android-m2repository
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'

before_install:
  - touch $HOME/.android/repositories.cfg
  - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
  - yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"

before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
  - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
  - $HOME/.android/build-cache

before_script:
  - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - ./gradlew clean build
  - ./gradlew test
```